# ¿Como comparo dos vectores y verificar si uno de los dos es el orden inverso del otro en C?

Tags: c

el problema es que z nunca desciende, siempre vale 3.

```
int main(){
    int n = 3;
    int v1[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int v2[] = {3, 2, 1};
    int z = n;
    int contador1=0, contador2=0, resultado;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (v1[i] == v2[z]) {
            printf("%i\n", z);
            contador1 += 1;
            i = i + 1;
            x = z - 1;
        }
    }

    for (int c=0;c<n;c++){
        if (v2[c] == v1[z]) {
            contador2 += 1;
            c = c + 1;
            z = z - 1;
        }
    }   

    if(contador1 > contador2) {
        resultado = contador1;
    }
    else{
        resultado = contador2;
    }

    return resultado; }
```

Comment: Muy bien, tienes el enunciado, ahora debes escribir el código del mismo. No lo haremos por ti. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. En [es.so] no hacemos los deberes de nadie.

Comment: Gracias Efe.. estaba en lo mismo que vos....

Comment: tal vez sea por esta linea?  x = z - 1;

Comment: `z` desciende sólo en el segundo for, cuando los dos elementos son iguales. Igual, si esa condición no se cumple bien podrías terminar de iterar y decir que no, no son el reflejo del otro. En el primer for nunca modificas z y sí lo usas para apuntar a elementos en v2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> el problema es que z nunca desciende, siempre vale 3

Eso es porque nunca decrementas `z`

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if (v1[i] == v2[z]) {
        printf("%i\n", z);
        contador1 += 1;
        i = i + 1;
        x = z - 1;
    }
}
```

Fíjate bien que, en la última línea del bucle, estás actualizando `x`, no `z`

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if (v1[i] == v2[z]) {
        printf("%i\n", z);
        contador1 += 1;
        i = i + 1;
        x = z - 1;
    //  ^ no es z
    }
}
```

Pero esto parece más un error sintáctico que el origen de tu problema, ya que si este fuese el problema el código no compilaría, pues `x` no está declarada en ningún sitio.

Sin embargo, hay dos problemas en tu código:

- `z` inicialmente debería valer 2, no 3. Recuerda que los índices empiezan en 0, luego la última posición del array vendrá dada por `n-1`, no por `n`

  ```
  int z = n; // <<--- ERROR
  ```
- Tras el primer bucle, no actualizas `z`, que valdrá 0. Como sigues decrementando `z`, esta tendrá valores negativos... el efecto es que el código accederá a posiciones que no pertenecen al array y ello hará que tu algoritmo no funcione correctamente.

Quizás quedaría más legible el código si declaras y actualizas `i` y `z` directamente en el bucle:

```
// int z = n - 1; <<--- declaración comentada (o borrada si quieres)

for (int i=0, z=n-1; i<n; i++, z--)
{
    if (v1[i] == v2[z]) {
        printf("%i\n", z);
        contador1 += 1;
    }
}
```

De esta forma ya no podrás reutilizar la misma variable `z` en el segundo bucle. Se te obligará a declarar una nueva variable `z` y a darle un valor inicial, con lo que el error desaparecerá solo